# How to remove a notification observer set in a closure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have this code:

```
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { field in
        field.placeholder = "password"
        field.secureTextEntry = true
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification,
            object: field, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { n in
                delete.enabled = field.text?.characters.count >= 2 }
    }
```

I'm wondering how I should go about removing the observer from "field" when the containing view is dismissed? Since 'field' only exists inside the closure, I'm not sure how to get a reference to it that I can pass to removeObserver later.

Or do I even need to remove the observer? Will it just remove itself when field is eventually deallocated?

**Update**

I realized that in this specific case, I can retrieve the reference to the field and remove the observer by doing:

```
        if let alert = alert, textFields = alert.textFields where textFields.count > 0 {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(textFields[0])
        }
```

But I'm going to leave the question up for a little because I'm curious about the general case where I do

```
{
let x = Object()
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("thing",
                object: x, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
}()
```

**Update to the update**

Per @rmaddy, my update was wrong. I was confusing the observer and the observing object.

Per @leo-dabus I should be doing

```
weakSelf?.observer = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification,
                object: field, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { n in
                    delete.enabled = field.text?.characters.count >= 2 }
```

And then later in the action that dismisses the alert:

```
if let observer = weakSelf?.deleteAlertObserver {
                                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(observer)
                            }
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`. It tells you how to remove the observer.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:) say "You must invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated." They don't say how to do it in this context where I've lost the reference to the observer. Unless I'm looking at the wrong docs.

Comment: You need to save the return value of `addObserverForName...` and use that value in the call to `removeObserver...`.

Comment: Well yes this question is asking how to do that. The addObserver call is made inside a closure and so the return value from it will go out of scope when the closure finishes. I need the observer to continue being active after the end of the specific closure and then remove it before the containing view is dismissed.

Comment: Declare the variable to store the return value outside of the disclosure.

Comment: @rogueleaderr declare var observer: AnyObject! as your view controller property

Comment: then observer = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName

Comment: @rogueleaderr Your update isn't correct. The text field isn't the observer. You must pass the return value of `addObserverForName` to `removeObserver`.

Comment: Now that your updated update is correct, you should actually post that as an answer instead of as an update to your question. It's fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the consensus answer here is that we should create a variable in the  outer scope to hold the reference to the observer that's created in the inner scope. Then when the observer is no longer needed, we can remove it. So, something along the lines of:

```
import UIKit

class Pointless
{
    var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

    init () {
        class SomeObject {}
        observer = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("something",
            object: SomeObject(), queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { n in
                print(n)
        }
    }

    deinit
    {
        if let observer = observer{
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you are storing a reference to the object returned from addObserverForName... not the object returned from your closure.

Comment: Yeah, although we could also store the object doing the observing and use that. We can do either removeObserver: (using the actual observer returned from addObserver) or removeObserver:name:object using the object that'll be receiving the notifications.

Comment: I have done the same and now on iPhone 5 registering an observer this way prevents deallocation of my view controller. Can somebody verify this please? I have n o idea how to solve this problem. My unit tests found this behaviour.